# For any prime $p$ of the form $4k + 3$, prove that $x^2 + \frac{p+1}{4} \equiv 0 \;(\text{mod }p)$ is not solvable

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, jacobi-symbol

I tried using quadratic reciprocity to simplify 
$$\left(\frac{-\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)$$ 
and tried replacing $p$ by $k$ $(\text{as in}\, p = 4k + 3)$, but don't know how to proceed after that.

Comment: Presumably your title should refer to $x^2+(p+1)/4\equiv0\pmod p$, not $\pmod 4$. Hint: multiply both sides of the congruence $x^2+(p+1)/4\equiv0\pmod p$ by $4$ and simplify.

Comment: thanks, i've edited the question. i'm not sure how to proceed after multiplying by 4, because of the coefficient of $x^2$ being 4 and not 1, i can't use properties of legendre symbol/jacobi. trying to further multiply it by $4^{-1}$ (mod p) seems to make it more complicated, since $4^{-1}$ (mod p) is (k+1), where p = 4k + 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2+\frac{p-1}{4}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ is solvable iff $\left(\frac{\color{red}{-}\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right) = 1$, that implies $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1$ by the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol. On the other hand $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ implies $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=-1$.

Comment: how does $\left(\frac{\color{red}{-}\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right) = 1$ imply $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1$? how did you simplify the $\left(\frac{\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)$ term?

Comment: @RakeshSinha: $\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)=1$ because $4$ is a square, hence $$\left(\frac{-\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-\frac{p+1}{4}}{p}\right)\left(\frac{4}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-(p+1)}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply both sides by $4$, as @GregMartin suggested you get
$$4x^2 + p + 1 \equiv 0\mod{p}.$$
This simplifies to
$$4x^2 \equiv -1\mod{p},\text{ or }(2x)^2 \equiv -1\mod{p}.$$
But $-1$ is not a square $\mod{p}$.